# how to make calculations and comparisons with the next line in R

Tags: r

i got stuck in a problem:

i got this df:

```
df <- data.frame(station         = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 Initial_height  = c(20, 50, 100, 30, 60),
                 final_height    = c(50, 100, 300, 60, 110),
                 initial_flow    = c(0.5, 1.2, 1.9, 0.8, 0.7),
                 final_Flow      = c(1.21, 1.92, 0.805, 0.7, 1))
```

context: each height has a flow value, but is calculated differently for each line of the data frame.

I would like to compare, for the same station, the flow value where the height is the same.

My perfect data frame:

```
  df.answer <- data.frame(station         = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                          Initial_height  = c(20, 50, 100, 30, 60),
                          final_height    = c(50, 100, 300, 60, 110),
                          initial_flow    = c(0.5, 1.2, 1.9, 0.8, 0.7),
                          final_Flow      = c(1.21, 1.92, 0.805, 0.7, 1),
                          diff_flow       = c(0.010, 0.020, NA, 0, NA))
```

NA can be replaced by any other character

*EDIT*: this can happen:

```
df <- data.frame(station         = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 Initial_height  = c(20, 51, 100, 30, 60),
                 final_height    = c(50, 100, 300, 60, 110),
                 initial_flow    = c(0.5, 1.2, 1.9, 0.8, 0.7),
                 final_Flow      = c(1.21, 1.92, 0.805, 0.7, 1),
                 diff_flow       = c(NA, 0.020, NA, 0, NA)))
```

at station A, the initial and final values ​​do not match. should return NA

Comment: What is the expected for that new ddata

Comment: NA, for example

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(station) %>% mutate(diff_flow = case_when(lead(lag(final_height) == Initial_height) ~ final_Flow - lead(initial_flow)))`

Comment: it works a lot, i'm trying to search what " ~ " do.

Comment: Thanks, it is a syntax symbol used by `case_when` to suggest that the expression on the `lhs` of `~` is TRUE, then do this.  By default, all the other cases will `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subtract the `lead` i.e next value of 'initial_flow' from 'final_flow after grouping by 'station'

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
  group_by(station) %>%
  mutate(diff_flow = final_Flow - lead(initial_flow)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  station Initial_height final_height initial_flow final_Flow diff_flow
#  <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A                   20           50          0.5      1.21       0.01
#2 A                   50          100          1.2      1.92       0.02
#3 A                  100           30          1.9      0.805     NA   
#4 B                   30           60          0.8      0.7        0   
#5 B                   60          110          0.7      1         NA
```

Comment: can you help me with the case in EDIT?

Comment: @BryanSouza sure, I will check that

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table` you can use `shift` to get next row in each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,diff_flow := final_Flow - shift(initial_flow, type = 'lead'), station]

#   station Initial_height final_height initial_flow final_Flow diff_flow
#1:       A             20           50          0.5      1.210      0.01
#2:       A             50          100          1.2      1.920      0.02
#3:       A            100          300          1.9      0.805        NA
#4:       B             30           60          0.8      0.700      0.00
#5:       B             60          110          0.7      1.000        NA
```